# Find Largest number in Python List using Recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I need to find the largest number in a list using recursion and without using `max`.

Example:

```
print(find_max_num([9,3,0,10])) # Should give output: 10
```

Comment: print(max([9,3,0,10]))

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. [See also.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def max(a, b):
    return a if a > b else b

def maximum(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        return max(L[0],maximum(L[1:]))
```

Comment: no this code uses max, I am not allowed to use max

Comment: @OrBarak I've added implementation for `max`

Comment: You should name in something other than `max`. Since `max` is a built-in (even if the OP doesn't want to use it) you shouldn't overwrite it.

Comment: is there another way to do it without calling any other function ?

Comment: @OrBarak You can do the ternary inline.